# My Python Program keeps giving me "s_label not defined", So it won't display my answer on the label

Tags: python, variables, defined

So my code basically differentiates a function that i insert and outputs it on "s_label". This worked all the time until i tried to make multiple pages for my program. Now all that happens is i receive the error of "s_label is not defined" and nothing else happens. i know the problem is in how i placed my code but i don't know how to fix it.

```
class PageOne(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Differentiation Calculator", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
    button1.pack()



    #This positions the label for f(x)
    Label(self, text='Enter f(x)').pack(side='left')


    #This inputs the Function f(x), f(x) = (f_entry)
    f_entry = Entry(self, width=12)
    f_entry.pack(side='left')

    s_label = Label(self, width=20) 


    #This is the command that excecutes when we press the button ((Differentiate) f = )
    def calc(event=None):
        f_txt = f_entry.get()

        x = sp.Symbol('x') 

        res =  (sp.diff(f_txt,x))
        print(res)


        global s_label
        s_label.configure(text=res)   # display f(x) value

    Button(self, text=' (Differentiate) f = ', relief='flat',command=calc).pack(side='left')
    s_label.pack(side='left')
```

Comment: you should better change `s_label` as an attribute with `self.s_label`, and make the function `calc` a method of the class `PageOne`, to be able to call `self.s_label` (instead of global variable, `s_label` is defined in the scope of `__init__` it's not global)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't work
simpler example (does not work):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        x=20
        def func():
            global x
            print(x)
        func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
```

although this does:

```
x = 20
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        def func():
            global x
            print(x)
        func()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
```

So by this you get to know that using `global` you can use variables that are out of the scope of **all the nested functions**

Another working eg.

```
x = 20
def A():
    x = 30
    def B():
        global x
        print(x)
    B()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A()

>> 20
```

while this will give you the same error:

```
def A():
    x = 30
    def B():
        global x # You don't even require this statement over here
        print(x)
    B()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    A()
```

for your specific case you can use the `self` variable which will bind any of your variable to the instance of that class which you can use and modify anywhere referencing it by `self.variable_name` which will edit/display the value for the entire class instance.